# how to hide default video browser controls when click full screen

Tags: javascript

I create my custom javascript video controls but when I click full screen I want to be able to hide the default control and include my custom controls.

```
function toggleFullScreen() {

    if( vid.requestFullScreen ) {

        vid.requestFullScreen();

    } else if( vid.webKitRequestFullScreen ) {

        vid.webKitRequestFullScreen();

    } else if( vid.mozRequestFullScreen ) {

        vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will hide default controls when click fullscreen

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```

[for more details just go here](http://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/)